# Neo4j: Simple query taking too much time

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a `User` class which is related to other users (`User`) via `FRIEND` relationship.

Now I want to get the list of all friends of a user. For that my cypher query (below) is taking too much time in very less data.

I have 100 `User` nodes and each node is linked to at least 10 users and at most 20 users. But my query below is taking around 8 seconds.

```
@Query(
    "MATCH (user:User {uid:{0}})-[:FRIEND]-(friend:User)" +
    "RETURN friend"
)
public List<User> getFriends(String userId);
```

**Neo4j version:** 2.x

**Spring-data-neo4j version:** 3.x

My other two queries are also not very fast. First one taking around 200ms and second one taking 1500ms

```
@Query(
//        "MATCH (user:User {uid:{0}})-[:PLAYED_SONG|DOWNLOADED_SONG]->(song:Song {songId:{1}})<-[:PLAYED_SONG|DOWNLOADED_SONG]-(otherUser:User) " +
    "MATCH (user:User {uid:{0}}), (song:Song {songId:{1}})<-[:PLAYED_SONG|DOWNLOADED_SONG]-(otherUser:User) " +
    "WHERE (user)-[:FRIEND]-(otherUser) " +
    "RETURN otherUser " +
    "LIMIT 20"
)
public Set<User> getFriendsPlayedDownloadedSong(String userId, String songId);

@Query(
    "MATCH (user:User {uid:{0}})-[:FRIEND]-(friend:User)-[:PLAYED_SONG|DOWNLOADED_SONG]-(song:Song) " +
    "RETURN song " +
    "LIMIT 20"
)
public Set<Song> getFriendsListenedToSongs(String userId);
```

**Related Post:** [Same cypher query taking different time when executed through different consoles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24508892/spring-neo4j-queries-executed-through-neo4j-takes-much-more-time-compared-to-ex)